# Run python-script from CMD - windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

I want to run my python script without the `python` keyword at the beginning.

Example :
I don't want `python script.py`.

I want `script.py`

The problem is that when I run it how I want the script opens in a text editor, and it doesn't run in the console...

Why?

Comment: do you want to run python script from command prompt without using python as prefix? any specific reason?

Comment: Yes, I do...
I wanna make a CLI tool, I don't want to use the `python` prefix every time I run it.

Comment: Type `ftype /?` and `assoc /?`. If you also want to dump the `.py` part - see `set pathext`. If it's just one file see `doskey /?`. Batch files are also used for this. The dup is similar problem and cause but is **bash** specific.

Comment: It's not a duplicate...

I've ran it like so on another computer, without the `python` prefix, and it works..

Now - on windows 10 it opens the file in a text-editor instead running it!

Answer (score -1):

I just had to set the default opening of the file with python.exe,
By default it was with VS Code.

Comment: That's what the commands I told you do. But in a command prompt.

Comment: You should've been more explanatory!!!!